# web.py: Get the original web request

Tags: python, http-headers, web.py

I need to access to the original http request that the browser send to the server in `web.py`.

E.g., this is the request that Chromium issues when I surf to some page:

```
$ nc -l 8081
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8081
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/25.0.1364.160 Chrome/25.0.1364.160 Safari/537.22
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

I tried to get that from the [`web.ctx.env`](http://webpy.org/cookbook/ctx), but that's a dictionary (while I'd prefer the original raw text request) and it's mixed with some other data:

```
SERVER_SOFTWARE: CherryPy/3.2.0 Server
SCRIPT_NAME: 
ACTUAL_SERVER_PROTOCOL: HTTP/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD: GET
PATH_INFO: /
SERVER_PROTOCOL: HTTP/1.1
QUERY_STRING: 
HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/25.0.1364.160 Chrome/25.0.1364.160 Safari/537.22
HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-alive
REMOTE_PORT: 55409
SERVER_NAME: localhost
REMOTE_ADDR: 127.0.0.1
wsgi.url_scheme: http
SERVER_PORT: 8081
wsgi.input: <web.wsgiserver.KnownLengthRFile object at 0x940b16c>
HTTP_HOST: 127.0.0.1:8081
wsgi.multithread: True
REQUEST_URI: /
HTTP_ACCEPT: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
wsgi.version: (1, 0)
wsgi.run_once: False
wsgi.errors: <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0xb73010d0>
wsgi.multiprocess: False
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: gzip,deflate,sdch
```

This is the code I used to obtain the output above:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import web

urls = ('(.*)', 'urlhandler')

class urlhandler:
  def GET(self, url):
    txt = ""
    for k, v in web.ctx.env.items():
      txt += ": ".join([k, str(v)]) + "\n"
    return txt

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = web.application(urls, globals())
  app.run()
```

Should I purge this dictionary from unwanted data or is there a straightforward way to get the original request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Andrey's suggestion I came out with this code. It tries to reconstruct the web request, maybe this is not the best way to get it, but it's the only way I found to do that until now.

This program will display the web request of the requested page (it works for both POST and GET requests):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import web
from urllib import quote

urls = ('(.*)', 'urlhandler')

def adaptHeader(txt):
  """Input: string, header name as it is in web.ctx.env
  Output: string, header name according to http protocol.
  es: "HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL" => "Cache-Control"
  """
  txt = txt.replace('HTTP_', '')
  return '-'.join((t[0] + t[1:].lower() for t in txt.split('_')))

def rawRequest(env):
  """Reconstruct and return the web request based on web.ctx.env"""

  # url reconstruction
  # see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#url-reconstruction
  url = env['wsgi.url_scheme']+'://' # http/https
  url += env.get('HTTP_HOST') or (env['SERVER_NAME']+':'+env['SERVER_PORT']) # host + port
  url += quote(env.get('SCRIPT_NAME', ''))
  url += quote(env.get('PATH_INFO', ''))
  url += ('?' + env['QUERY_STRING']) if env.get('QUERY_STRING') else '' # GET querystring

  # get/post request
  req = ' '.join((env['REQUEST_METHOD'], url, env['SERVER_PROTOCOL'])) + '\n'

  # headers
  for k, v in env.items():
    if k.startswith('HTTP') or k in ('CONTENT_TYPE', 'CONTENT_LENGTH'):
      req += adaptHeader(k) + ': ' + str(v) + '\n'

  # post data 
  try:
    req += '\n' + env['wsgi.input'].read(int(env['CONTENT_LENGTH']))
  except:
    pass

  return req

class urlhandler:
  def GET(self, url):
    return rawRequest(web.ctx.env)
  def POST(self, url):
    return rawRequest(web.ctx.env)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = web.application(urls, globals())
  app.run()
```

Comment: It seems you can calculate request url much simpler: `web.ctx.home + web.ctx.fullpath`. Check this: http://webpy.org/cookbook/ctx

Answer (score 1):

Looking at what you have, you may filter `web.ctx.env` by the keys that start with "HTTP_". It would be easier than obtaining and parsing raw request headers.

You may check wsgi spec here http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#environ-variables

> HTTP_ Variables Variables corresponding to the client-supplied HTTP
>   request headers (i.e., variables whose names begin with "HTTP_"). The
>   presence or absence of these variables should correspond with the
>   presence or absence of the appropriate HTTP header in the request.

Comment: Thanks, maybe this is the only way to obtain that. Anyway I wouldn't have to parse the request, I just need it as it is.